# Hbase Cloudera java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcScheduler.getWriteQueueLength

Tags: hadoop, exception, cloudera, apache-phoenix

I am using Cloudera CDH for my Hadoop Cluster. Suddenly, I noticed that I have the following errors in my HBase log files. These errors occur every time no matter what job I run. How do I fix the errors? P.S. So far they didn't cause any serious failover.

So these errors happen in the second cluster too.

> ```
> log   /jmx javax.management.RuntimeErrorException: getMBeanInfo threw Error
>   at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getMBeanInfo(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1387)
>   at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.getMBeanInfo(JmxMBeanServer.java:920)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.JSONBean.write(JSONBean.java:125)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.JSONBean.access$000(JSONBean.java:53)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.JSONBean$1.write(JSONBean.java:96)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.http.jmx.JMXJsonServlet.doGet(JMXJsonServlet.java:202)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
>   at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
>   at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1221)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter.doFilter(StaticUserWebFilter.java:113)
>   at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.http.ClickjackingPreventionFilter.doFilter(ClickjackingPreventionFilter.java:48)
>   at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.http.HttpServer$QuotingInputFilter.doFilter(HttpServer.java:1354)
>   at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.http.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:49)
>   at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.http.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:49)
>   at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
>   at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:399)
>   at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
>   at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
>   at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:767)
>   at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:450)
>   at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
>   at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>   at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
>   at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
>   at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:928)
>   at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
>   at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
>   at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
>   at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
>   at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
> ```

```
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
> org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcScheduler.getWriteQueueLength()I
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.MetricsHBaseServerWrapperImpl.getWriteQueueLength(MetricsHBaseServerWrapperImpl.java:87)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.MetricsHBaseServerSourceImpl.getMetrics(MetricsHBaseServerSourceImpl.java:228)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter.getMetrics(MetricsSourceAdapter.java:199)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter.updateJmxCache(MetricsSourceAdapter.java:182)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter.getMBeanInfo(MetricsSourceAdapter.java:155)
>           at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getMBeanInfo(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1378)
>           ... 34 more
>         View Log File
>         ws-hadoop-data-4  ERROR   December 19, 2017 2:59 AM   log 
>         Nested in javax.management.RuntimeErrorException: getMBeanInfo threw Error:
>         java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcScheduler.getWriteQueueLength()I
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.MetricsHBaseServerWrapperImpl.getWriteQueueLength(MetricsHBaseServerWrapperImpl.java:87)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.MetricsHBaseServerSourceImpl.getMetrics(MetricsHBaseServerSourceImpl.java:228)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter.getMetrics(MetricsSourceAdapter.java:199)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter.updateJmxCache(MetricsSourceAdapter.java:182)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter.getMBeanInfo(MetricsSourceAdapter.java:155)
>           at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getMBeanInfo(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1378)
>           at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.getMBeanInfo(JmxMBeanServer.java:920)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.JSONBean.write(JSONBean.java:125)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.JSONBean.access$000(JSONBean.java:53)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.JSONBean$1.write(JSONBean.java:96)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.http.jmx.JMXJsonServlet.doGet(JMXJsonServlet.java:202)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1221)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter.doFilter(StaticUserWebFilter.java:113)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.http.ClickjackingPreventionFilter.doFilter(ClickjackingPreventionFilter.java:48)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.http.HttpServer$QuotingInputFilter.doFilter(HttpServer.java:1354)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.http.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:49)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.http.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:49)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:399)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:767)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:450)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:928)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
>           at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
>           at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Comment: maybe ripple restart? but it looks like metrics may be overwhelmed?

Comment: @PaulBastide, maybe it would help but I don't use licensed version of Cloudera. It have one more cluster with different nodes. I checked it. That cluster had the same errors too.